# Why does my code work on some rows of the array and not others?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

So for my university practice work (professor not answering these days) I have to write a program in C that receives a 2D array from the user and then searches for sequences of 3 or more zeroes in it.
EX:

```
1 1 1 1 0 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 1 1
```

Should output:

```
no sequence in: 1
no sequence in: 2
Sequence found in: 3 row
no sequence in: 4
Sequence found in: 5 row
```

I wrote these simple loops but I get some weird outputs that don't lead me to a fix, my code is:

```
int main() {
    int array[ROW][COLUMN];
    printf("please enter a 5x5 matrix: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; ++j) {
            scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    int zero_c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; ++j) {

                if (array[i][j] == 0) {
                zero_c = 1;
                if (array[i][j+1] == 0) {
                    zero_c = 1;
                    if (array[i][j + 2] == 0) {
                        zero_c = 1;
                    }
                }
            }else {
                    zero_c = 0;
                }
        }


        if (zero_c==1) {
            printf("Sequence found at: %d row\n ", i + 1);
            zero_c = 0;
        } else {
            printf("no sequence in: %d\n", i + 1);
        }
    }


        return 0;

}
```

Which outputs: (for the same array shown above)

```
Sequence found at: 1 row //(it seems like it always finds a sequence on the first row)
 no sequence in: 2
Sequence found at: 3 row
 Sequence found at: 4 row
 no sequence in: 5
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with the code:

1. It will index past the end of the row, resulting in false matches (and possible undefined behavior).
2. Once it finds a sequence of 3 zeros in a row, it doesn't stop looking in that row, so if the row contains a 1 after the zeros, it forgets that it ever saw the zeros, resulting in missed matches.

Problem (1) is easily fixed by changing the loop test for the inner loop to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN - 2; ++j) {
```

The second problem is fixed by adding a `break` statement once 3 zeros have been found in a row

The resulting loop looks like:

```
    int zero_c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN - 2; ++j) {
            if (array[i][j] == 0) {
                zero_c = 1;
                if (array[i][j+1] == 0) {
                    zero_c = 1;
                    if (array[i][j + 2] == 0) {
                        zero_c = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                zero_c = 0;
            }
        }
        ...
```

This should fix the bugs (provided it continues to reset `zero_c` at the end of outer loop, as it does now).

A simpler version would be as follows:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        int zero_c = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN - 2; ++j) {
            if (array[i][j] == 0 && array[i][j+1] == 0 && array[i][j+2] == 0) {
                zero_c = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        ...
```

This version resets `zero_c` at the top of the outer loop, and doesn't require it to be reset when printing the result for each row.

A more efficient version simply keeps a counter, with no need for look-ahead.  Note that for this version, the original inner loop bound needs to be used:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        int zero_c = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; ++j) {
            if (array[i][j] == 0) {
                zero_c++;
                if (zero_c == 3)
                    break;
            }
            else {
                zero_c = 0;
            }
        }
        ...
```

For this version, you would check to see of `zero_c == 3` when printing the status of a row (and again, there would be no need to reset it there).

Comment: Thank you so much, your explanation was very clear!

Comment: @JorgeÁvilaBalmaceda No problem!  If this answers your question, you should mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: woops!, didn't notice that